# Mysql update table using ubuntu terminal

Tags: mysql, update, ubuntu

I have a CSV file that has 2 columns

```
Name 
Email
```

I have a table in my database that has the same columns + some extra columns.

Now I would like to update my db table using that csv file. I mean like this

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `email` = 'csvemail' WHERE `name` = 'csvname'
```

Can someone help me to do that from my ubuntu terminal?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has built-in support for importing data from CSV files, just use the command-line client :

> mysql -u `<user>` -p

(replace `<user>` with your MySQL username and enter the password when asked to)

Then, tell MySQL to use your database :

> `USE <database>;`

(replace `<database>` with the database name)

And finally, use this to import everything from your CSV file :

> `LOAD DATA INFILE '<path>' INTO TABLE <table>;`

(replace `<path>` with the full path to the CSV file such as `/home/user/file.csv` and `<table>` with the table name).

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077801/import-csv-to-mysql-table?lq=1) one that may be related to your question.